# How to programatically filter log entries from GCP log?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, logging, google-cloud-functions

I have a hard time figuring out how to programatically get specific GCP log entries.

I have multiple Cloud Functions in my project. They all write logs to a log named `cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions` (maybe it is possible to have separate logs for each cloud function but that is another question I should ask I guess :-)

By using the [client library for logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) I do the following to retrieve a few log entries, which works fine:

```
const log = logging.log('cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions');
const [entries] = await log.getEntries({
      autoPaginate: false, 
      pageSize: 5
 });
```

However, I now want to retrieve *only* entries from one of my cloud functions (function-x) and try to find any details on what to put in the query object for the `log.getEntries(query)` call. As most GCP users know, finding API information in GCP is sometimes a bit of a hustle... The closest I've gotten regarding the API method above is [this page](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/logging/latest/logging/protos.google.logging.v2.listlogentriesrequest). It list a `public resourceNames: string[]` property which I try to use, but apparently I do something wrong and need help.

I try e.g.

```
const [entries] = await log.getEntries({
        autoPaginate: false, 
        pageSize: 5, 
        resourceNames: ['projects/my-project-id/function-x']
 });
```

But cannot get it to work. I just get an

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Received unexpected value parsing name "projects/my-project-id/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions/function-x": my-project-id. Expected the form projects/[PROJECT_ID]
```

So, my question is: How do I do to get log entries from function-x only?

As specified in the page defining resourceNames, the query object also has a `filter` property but no details on how to use it. A second question is therefore how can this filter property be used? What format does it require? (Once I can retrieve logs from my function I would for example like to filter them on labels and severity).

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the library?

Comment: hmm, actually not I just noticed. I have 9.9.0 installed and latest is 10.1.10..

Comment: And so, is it better?

Comment: I just had a chance to test with latest lib, but the error remains. The error message changed slightly, now it says:
`Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Received unexpected value parsing name "projects/my-project-id/function-x": my-project-id. Expected the form projects/[PROJECT_ID]`.  

If I change the code to `resourceNames: ['projects/my-project-id']` it doesn't throw an error but of course, doesn't do what I want either...

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the response to this (my) question. If I use teh following it works:

```
const [entries] = await log.getEntries({
        autoPaginate: false, 
        pageSize: 5,
        filter: 'resource.labels.function_name=function-x',
        resourceNames: ['projects/my-project-id']
 });
```

Turns out, as [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rpc/google.logging.v2#google.logging.v2.ListLogEntriesRequest), resourceNames should be one of

```
projects/[PROJECT_ID]
organizations/[ORGANIZATION_ID]
billingAccounts/[BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID]
folders/[FOLDER_ID]
```

and the function name should be placed in the filter instead.